# Python Problems with Guessing Numbers

Tags: python

"""

I am new to coding in general and I have looked up how to fix this but when I input a letting than
a letting 2x then a number this happens

```
ges a number 1 tho 100 t
your ges is t
plz input a positive number below 100 that is not a word. exmp(42)
ges a number 1 tho 100 w
your ges is w
plz input a positive number below 100 that is not a word. exmp(42)
```

this is where I get confused

```
 ges a number 1 tho 100 2
 your ges is 2
 2
 your ges is t
 plz input a positive number below 100 that is not a word. exmp(42)
 ges a number 1 tho 100 2
 your ges is 2
 2
 None
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "c:\Users\BertD\OneDrive\Desktop\random_number_gessing_game.py", line 20, in<module>
         ges = int(ges)
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 't'
```

I am concerned about how python is coming up with this?
It's a tuff puzzle to solve for me.

"""

```
import random

ges = input("ges a number 1 tho 100 ")

def valid_ges(num):

while True:
    print("your ges is "+str(num))
    if num.isdigit():
        print(num)
        break
    elif num != num.isdigit():
        print("plz input a positive number below 100 that is not a word. exmp(42)")
        num = input("ges a number 1 tho 100 ")

    elif num > 100:
        print("try a number below 100")
        num = input("pic a number 1 tho 100 ")

valid_ges(ges)

print(valid_ges(ges))

r = random.randint(1, 100)

ges = int(ges)

while ges != r:

    if (ges <= 100):
        print("your "+str(r - ges)+" away")
        ges = abs(int(input("pic a number 1 tho 100 ")))
    elif(ges == r):
        break

print("yay you did it")
```

thank you for your time and have a nice day!

Comment: Think about what you get from `num.isdigit()`. Can `num` ever be equal to this value? [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You should step through your code in a [debugger](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) and observe how its execution differs from your expectations

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask],
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and [formatting help](/help/formatting) so you can correctly format your [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that giving you the solution will be beneficial for your learning process. Instead, I'll try to point out where your mistake is.

The main problem is in your function `valid_guess`. You successfully look if your input is a valid number. However, you never *give back* this information to the rest of your program. Instead, you do `print(num)` whenever the user input is valid, which only shows the valid guess on the screen. This value is however not stored anywhere.

You should have a good look at `return` in python. When you write a function that needs to process some information and then forward that information back to the rest of the program, you use `return` statements instead. Let me show this with an example:

```py
def square(num):
    print(num**2)

>>> x = 5
>>> square(x)
25
>>> xsquared = square(x)
25
>>> print(xsquared)
None
```

Do you see how the result is not stored in `xsquared`? It just shows the result to the user, then completely forgets about it!

If I however use this instead:

```py
def square(num):
    return(num**2)

>>> x = 5
>>> xsquared = square(x)
>>> print(xsquared)
25
```

The result is now successfully stored! Do note however that we didn't ask the program to show us the results this time. To do so, we need to add another `print` statement, as you can see in the last line!

Try to use this information to your problem now. Try to store the new guess in `ges` whenever you give a valid number.

As @pranav-hosangadi mentioned, you should have a close look at a python debugger and learn to work with it. This will help you understand your code much better! Good luck with learning, and feel free to comment if you have more questions!

Comment: I will make sure to do that thank you and everyone else for all the help. the examples are a big help it lets me find out how python works and let me apply it to my program.

Answer (score 0):

This a python value error which occurs when you try to convert a string value that is not formatted as an integer.
Here, the line which causes the error is `ges = int(ges)`.
Where when you first executed you are giving(ges) it a String `t`. It's not changing it's value while guessing again. Go through your code.

Comment: ok thank you =) your a big help